# Using JSON with AJAX and Python database

Tags: javascript, python, json, ajax, database

I am new to python and am trying to access the db though python and return some results in a JSON array using AJAX.
I test it by returning a JSON list and alerting it using js. it works when I don't use the db connection but as soon as I add it the js alert stops too. the db connection seems to work properly when I run the file `getSchedule.py`. the db connection is in a separate file `webairdb.py`
Can someone please try to help me figure out whats wrong?

#### getSchedule.py

```
#!D:/Programming/Software/python3.4.4/python
import sys, json,cgi, cgitb, mysql.connector, webairdb

cgitb.enable()
fs = cgi.FieldStorage()

sys.stdout.write("Content-Type: application/json")

sys.stdout.write("\n")
sys.stdout.write("\n")

conn = webairdb.getConnection()
conn.close()

listr = [11111]

sys.stdout.write(json.dumps(listr))
sys.stdout.write("\n")

sys.stdout.close()
```

#### webairdb.py

```
#!D:/Programming/Software/python3.4.4/python
import cgi, cgitb, imp, mysql.connector

host ="localhost"
db = "webair"
user = "root"
password = ""

def getConnection():
    conn =   mysql.connector.connect(user=user,password=password,host=host,database=db)
    if conn.is_connected():
        print("aaaqqqq")
    return conn
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **webairdb.py** you write to `sys.stdout` (that is what `print` does) - putting effectively breaking the json output. (You might want to have a look at the output by pressing F12 in your browser)

So just remove it and either write to `sys.stderr` or use [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial) instead.

You should also consider using [wsgi](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wsgiref.html) instead of cgi which makes things a bit easier (no need to care about printing at all) or a framework like [bottle](http://bottlepy.org) or [cherrypy](http://cherrypy.org/).

Comment: Thanx a lot. I was asked to do this without using any frameworks.